# Web Admin Graph Display: No luck with Cypher?

Tags: neo4j

In the Web Admin graph display view on Neo4J 1.9.1, any idea why a Cypher query like the following will return nodes in `list` view, but not in the visual `graph` view?

```
START n=node(*) RETURN n;
```

Querying on an individual node ID (e.g. 3) works just fine, display in both `graph` and `list` views.

Comment: How many nodes do you have in the graph database?

Comment: Sounds like a performance issue on the JS client side, as @Nicholas is suspecting.

Comment: Yes, trying to return and display all the nodes may not be feasible if you have a large graph.